# How do I change the format of Python's datetime.timedelta output to YYMMDD?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import datetime for i in range(0, 180): 
    print((datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(i)))
```

I found the above snippet of code that does *almost* what I want except the output is formatted incorrrectly for my needs.
I would like to see

```
20190312
20190313
20190314
```

**instead of**

```
2019-03-12
2019-03-13
2019-03-14
```

Do I need to use **return** instead of **print** and then run datetime.strftime('%Y%m%d') on the returned object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `strftime` method:

```
for i in range(0, 180):
    print((datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(i)).strftime('%Y%m%d'))
```